# Is there an example for Angular2 with i18n using Webpack?

Tags: angular, internationalization, webpack

I am trying to integrate i18n in my Angular 2 app using Webpack. The official documentation from angular describes it using SystemJS. Does anyone know some good example how to do a proper i18n setup for Angular 2 using Webpack?

Comment: Just follow the steps on this repo : https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

Comment: And if I am bound to the native i18n mechanism from angular? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html